# ICMPv6 Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-10, networking, ipv6, windows-firewall, icmp

I've added a simple custom incoming rule in my Windows 10's Firewall to allow all ICMPv6 packets without any limitation, but still https://ipv6-test.com/ reports as filtered.
If I disable the firewall, everything works. I also reset Windows Firewall in the process of troubleshooting. I am on a private network, behind an home router and IPv6 is from Hurricane Electrics.

I already saw the other topics related to this question but couldn't find any answer.
I wouldn't like to disable the firewall entirely because I have other rules in place, so what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: The default firewall rules are sufficient. Did you change them? Did you perhaps enable the "block all incoming traffic" checkbox?

Comment: I needed to reboot, it seems. Fixed now.